# How implement a ball similar as in this image use Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Image URL: [A image of disk usage](https://github.com/yuezheng/OpenTest/blob/master/abcdef.png)

This a usage of disk, how to implement it use Highcharts?

Comment: Do you really have to use Highcharts? this looks like something you can achieve with pure html/css

Comment: more importantly, why would you want to??  A simple bar will much better display the information, without confusion.

Comment: OK! You reminded me! I almost forgot how to use pure html/css! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a bar chart so . . .

What I'd look at doing is producing a 'normal' bar chart and then adding a circular 'mask' over the top of it to produce the round effect.